# How to retrieve broken links

Tags: php, hyperlink

I would like to retrieve broken links of a given website.
    I have this code but it doesn't work.
     Can you help me ?

// function to check url

```
        function check_url($url) {
            //echo "Test broken liens";
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch , CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            $data = curl_exec($ch);
            $headers = curl_getinfo($ch);
            curl_close($ch);

            return $headers['http_code'];

        }
        if(check_url("https://www.amazon.com/")==200){
            echo "<br> The link is validated <br>";
        }else{
            echo "<br>broken links<br>";
        }
```

// this function check all the code of a website and retrieve the tag of a hyperlink

```
         function getLinks(){
            $html = file_get_contents('https://www.amazon.com/');
            $dom = new domDocument;
            @$dom->loadHTML($html);
            $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
            $images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
            foreach ($images as $image) {
                $file= $image->getAttribute('href')."<br>"; 
                $lien=  "https://www.amazon.com/".$file;
                echo $lien;
                echo existenceLien($lien);
            }
        }
        echo getLinks();
```

// The target is to search the broken links in a website and worn the existence of those links
            //check if link exist and display the result for each

```
        function linkexistence($url){
// get the url
            $test = get_headers($url , 1);
            $message="";
// use preg_match function
            if (preg_match("#HTTP/1.1 200i#", $test[0])) {
                $message="Valid";
            }elseif (preg_match("#HTTP/1.1 404i#", $test[0])) {
                $message="Non-existent page ! (404)"; 
            }elseif (preg_match("#HTTP/1.1 301i#", $test[0])) {
                $message="The page has been moved";
            }elseif (preg_match("#HTTP/1.1 403i#", $test[0])) {
                $message="Access to the page refused! (403)";
            }else {
                $message="Invalid links";
            }
            return $message;
        }*****
```

Comment: _"I have this code but it doesn't work"_ - Please expand what _"doesn't work"_ means. Error messages? No result? Computer crashes? What debugging have you done? Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: i don't get the expected result

Comment: ...so we guessed since you posted a question here. We need to know what result you're expecting and what result you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

The mask is wrong in preg_match function, currently your mask is
`#HTTP/1.1 200i#`

but I believe that you have to use the following mask
`#HTTP/1.1 200#i`

thus you have to move the "i" after "#" in all your preg_match functions.

the "i" means the case sensitivity will be ignored

Comment: @adam92 Please rate the solution